# How to fix the warnings/errors that happens when using google-play-services for monodroid in xamarin?

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.android, google-play-services

I am working on an android application using google-maps and I noticed that I had all these warnings of "iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited e_pack_holo_dark.9.png" etc around 6 of them. 
Google maps wont work with the warning:
"'Android.GoogleMaps.MapActivity' is obsolete".

First I had the error of not finding the COMPILETODALVIK where I fixed it by going to project option->Android Build->Advanced->Java heap size and added 1G in that field that I have seen fixes that. It did fix the error, but all the warnings remain.

I fixed so that it is only using the "Minimum Android version" and "Target android version" to "Override-Android 5.0 (API level 21)"
As that has helped some people.

I am using Google Maps API v2 and have from the beginning.
And to do this I have followed guides from both google themselves and guides directed towards using C# with monodroid.

I have downloaded the API level 22 from the SDK Manager.

I have added all the permissions that I can get to work/ that has been recommended:

My android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="TrailMapplication.TrailMapplication">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <application android:label="TrailMapplication">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="MY_API_KEY" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

I have followed the guide on how to get the activity to work:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.GoogleMaps;

namespace TrailMapplication
{
    [Activity (Label = "MappActivity")]         
    public class MappActivity : MapActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Mapp);
            MapView mapView = (MapView)FindViewById (Resource.Id.mapView);
            mapView.SetBuiltInZoomControls (true);
            // Create your application here
        }
        protected override bool IsRouteDisplayed {
            get{ 
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have added the required api and so on into the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="My_API" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I recreated the problem in a new application, it happens when I add the google-play-services to any version of xamarin android.

Found the problem for the sRGB problem, my solution had for some reason cleaned out the value.xml and Mapp.axml when I added the google-play-services nuget package to the project. Went into the folder and re-added them into the project. But as it also had happened to the MappActivity, when I re-added that it got the "'Android.GoogleMaps.MapActivity' is obsolete" error back to.

What are possible other reasons for those kinds of warnings? 
And are there other possible solutions that I could try or something I missed to include?

Found where the problem lay: xamarin studio keeps deleting some parts of the project, usually files like activities, layouts and the AndroidManifest. I am unsure if it has to do with starting it with the emulator but that seem to be the case.

Comment: HAve you downloaded the latest Google play services using the Android SDK manager? At the bottom in extras download Google Play Services v22

Comment: Yes, I should add that to the things I have done.

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt the solution?

Comment: Yes, got another 4 warnings with the "iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited" when I re-did it now.